# How to retrive data from non-mapped field in embeded form

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to know if it's possible to get the data from a non-mapped field in an embeded form.

Here is the main form :

```
class PlayedLifeScoreType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //->add('nom')
        //->add('prenom')
        // NOTE: Use form collection to allow multiple `played` forms per JoueurType
        ->add('playeds', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PlayedLifeType::class,
            'label' => false,
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Partie::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

And the embedded one :

```
class PlayedLifeType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        /*->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('joueur', null, array(
             'data' => $event->getData() ?: options['joueur']
         ))*/
        //->add('joueur')
        ->add('joueur', TextType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'disabled' => 'true',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'tinymce'],
        ])
        ->add('max')              
        ->add('score')
        ->add('round', IntegerType::class,[
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Round',
        ])

        ;
    //});
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Played::class,
        'joueur' => null
    ]);
} 
}
```

And want to get the data from "round". I tried like this but doesn't work :

```
$r = $mainForm->get('playeds')->get("round")->getData();
```

I get this error :

> Child "round" does not exist.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

field "playeds" is a CollectionType.
So, for each entry, there is a 'round' value
To access this, you should do something like:

```
 foreach ($mainForm->get('playeds') as $played) {
    //you can access round here with $played->get('round')->getData()
    //Or the Played object with $played->getData()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. As it's a non-mapped field, I get this error : "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getRound" of class "App\Entity\Played".

Comment: I get the same error message : Attempted to call an undefined method named "getData" of class "App\Entity\Played".

Comment: You have not remove the getData() in the foreach loop

Comment: In my case, I only have 1 value within it (dont ask me why...). So for me I used: `$form->get('collectionFromFirstType')[0]->get('fieldOfSecondType')->getData();`. Works perfect.